# Joining multiple tables in list item with cursor

Tags: java, android, cursor, ormlite

I have one problem. I have a note that contains text data, and user can add multiple photos related to that note. Notes and photos are stored in separated tables, and both of data models for notes and photos extends abstract object with data that is relevant for both objects. Beside that, "note" table is foreign key for "photo" object.

Abstract class that both objects extends:

```
public abstract class SyncObject implements Parcelable {

public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String DATE = "date";
public static final String IS_SAVED_TO_CLOUD = "isSavedToCloud";
public static final String TIME_STAMP = "timeStamp";
public static final String IS_DELETED = "isDeleted";

@DatabaseField(id = true, index = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = ID)
public String id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = DATE)
public String date;

@DatabaseField(columnName = IS_SAVED_TO_CLOUD)
public boolean isSavedToCloud;

@DatabaseField(columnName = TIME_STAMP)
public String timeStamp;

@DatabaseField(columnName = IS_DELETED)
public boolean isDeleted; }
```

Here's note class:

```
public class Note extends SyncObject implements Parcelable {

public static final String TITLE = "title";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";

@DatabaseField(columnName = TITLE)
public String title;

@DatabaseField(columnName = DESCRIPTION)
public String description; }
```

And photo class:

```
public class Photo extends SyncObject{

public static final String FIELD_REF = "note";
public static final String PHOTO = "photo";
public static final String THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";

@DatabaseField(columnName = PHOTO)
public String photoUrl;

@DatabaseField(columnName = THUMBNAIL)
public String thumbnailUrl;

@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_REF, canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
public Note note;
```

So, here it begins.
I want to show photo related to note in list, but getting cursor with joining tables produced data with same fields, and querying by those fields doesn't make any sense. Basically, i want to show one note with one photo inside list.

I tried to do this with 2 cursors, but without any success. Am I making mistake in joining cursors or creating cursor in a first place?

I have Content Provider that creates 2 cursors, one for note and one for photo data. I'm able to show data in list from one at the time. Is there any way to show data from multiple(note & photo) tables with one cursor?

Creating cursor with rawQuerry created table with same fields, and i don't need fields from SyncObject for photos while showing notes in list.

Query I used:`Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM note INNER JOIN photos ON note = photos.note WHERE photos.note = note", null);`

Thanks in advance, if someone needs more info, ill update this post, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the question correctly, can you use column aliases for columns you want instead of * ? something like "SELECT n.*, p.photos, p.thumbnail FROM note n INNER JOIN photos p ON note = p.note WHERE photos.note = note"

Comment: When i join tables like that, i get wrong photos joined with wrong notes, and i get list with bunch of unrelated items. Basically, list looks like " WHERE photos.note = note" is ignored.

Comment: Looking at the example I don't see the relation (which column) between 'note' table and 'photos' table. I would expect either ID of the Note to be in the Photos table (more photos for one note) or  ID of the photo in the Note table (one photo per note) then you would use this in the join condition. 
Also using columns prefixed with table names should remove any ambiguity for the query executor - use db.rawQuery(„SELECT note.title, note.description, photos.thumbnail FROM note INNER JOIN photos ON notes.XXX = photos.XXX WHERE photos.note = ?“, new String[] {„xyz“})